# Create custom SharePoint subsite template/definition

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-template, site-definition

How could I create a template for a subsite? I have only got it to work to create a template for a site collection, using a site definition.

How should I do it when using a subsite ?

Here is a guide, http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/206829.aspx but I want to do like this but using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Creating site definitions for site collections is the same as creating them for subsites, you will need to make sure that the features activated in your onet.xml for the subsite definition are scopred to web not site.

Comment: How do u mean? An example?

Comment: i dont have a feature for my site definition?

Comment: i dont have entered anything in onet.xml?

Comment: i want to create a subsite on my publishing site and not only in root site ?

Comment: Yes, you need to create another configuration for your site, similar to the configuration you did for you root site definition, this way you will have another type of site you can use. Refer to these articles: http://www.rajbandi.net/sharepoint-2010-creating-a-site-definition-using-visual-studio-2010/

http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/post/2012/03/27/sharepoint-2010-site-definitions-site-templates.aspx

Comment: Hi. I have already done this in vs. I can still only create my template in root and not in publishing site.

Comment: I can only create sites and subsites at root site not inside site collection site? I want to create subsite inside a site collection based on a template?

Comment: i found the problem i should select english language then it show upp, when having my own language it dont displays

Comment: Sure, site definitions are scoped to the language, but as mentioned, it follows the same way as doing the root site definition.